# Android - Espresso - scrolling to a non-list View item

Tags: android, android-espresso

Is there a general approach for scrolling to non-list View items that are not yet visible on the screen?

Without any precautions, Espresso will indicate that "No Views in hierarchy found matching with id .....

I found this answer ... is this the best approach?

```
onView( withId( R.id.button)).perform( scrollTo(), click());
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [`scrollTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions.html#scrollTo()) JavaDoc, to use the code you specified ( `onView( withId( R.id.button)).perform( scrollTo(), click());` ), the preconditions are: "must be a descendant of ScrollView" and "must have visibility set to `View.VISIBLE`". If that is the case, then that will work just fine.

If it is in an `AdapterView`, then you should use [`onData`](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/advanced/index.html#matching-data-using-ondata-and-a-custom-viewmatcher) instead. In some cases, you may have to implement the `AdapterViewProtocol`, if your `AdapterView` is not well behaved.

If it is neither in an `AdapterView` nor a child of a `ScrollView`, then you would have to implement a custom `ViewAction`.

Comment: "it is neither in an AdapterView nor a child of a ScrollView" eg. NestedScrollView you can add Barista dependency and use fallowing method: scrollTo(R.id.<view_id>);
https://github.com/SchibstedSpain/Barista#baristas-assertions-api

Comment: In fact it is slightly better than only ScrollView's. Looking at the implementation of the ScrollToAction (the ViewAction returned by scrollTo()), HorizontalScrollView's and ListView's are also supported. https://git.io/fh7LO

Answer (score 4):

If you have a view inside `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `scrollView` `scrollTo()` does not work.

In order to work you need to create a class that implements `ViewAction` just like `ScrollToAction` but allows `NestedScrollView`s:

```
public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
    return allOf(
        withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE), 
        isDescendantOfA(anyOf(
            isAssignableFrom(ScrollView.class), 
            isAssignableFrom(HorizontalScrollView.class), 
            isAssignableFrom(NestedScrollView.class))
        )
    );
}
```

extra tip and access the action like:

```
public static ViewAction betterScrollTo() {
    return actionWithAssertions(new AllScrollViewsScrollToAction());
}
```

But with this scroll it does not trigger events from the layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

The code `onView( withId( R.id.button)).perform( scrollTo(), click());` will work if the view is descendant of ScrollView, HorizontalScrollView or ListView.

If we have `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` and for those who don't want to look into `ScrollToAction` class code I wrote the sample.

As Bruno Oliveira [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36649443/11998670) we can do something like this:

```
class ScrollToActionImproved : ViewAction {

override fun getConstraints(): Matcher<View> {
    return allOf(
        withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE),
        isDescendantOfA(
            anyOf(
                isAssignableFrom(ScrollView::class.java),
                isAssignableFrom(HorizontalScrollView::class.java),
                isAssignableFrom(NestedScrollView::class.java)
            )
        )
    )
}

override fun getDescription(): String = "scroll to view"

override fun perform(uiController: UiController?, view: View?) {
    if (isDisplayingAtLeast(90).matches(view)) {
        //View is already displayed
        return
    }
    val rect = Rect()
    view!!.getDrawingRect(rect)
    if (!view.requestRectangleOnScreen(rect, true)) {
        //Scrolling to view was requested, but none of the parents scrolled.
    }
    uiController!!.loopMainThreadUntilIdle()
    if (!isDisplayingAtLeast(90).matches(view)) {
        throw PerformException.Builder()
            .withActionDescription(this.description)
            .withViewDescription(HumanReadables.describe(view))
            .withCause(
                RuntimeException(
                    "Scrolling to view was attempted, but the view is not displayed"
                )
            )
            .build()
    }
}
```

}

And use it like this:

```
fun scrollToImproved(): ViewAction =
    actionWithAssertions(ScrollToActionImproved())

/* some logic */

onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(scrollToImproved())
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Code that worked for me is:

```
ViewInteraction tabView = onView(allOf(
    childAtPosition(childAtPosition(withId(R.id.bottomControlTabView), 0), 1), 
    isDisplayed()));
tabView.perform(click());
tabView.perform(click());

public static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, 
                                            final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent)
                        && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
```