# Espresso: How do I scroll to an item in a HorizontalScrollView by index?

Tags: android, android-espresso, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

This is what my `HorizontalScrollView` looks like:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_below="@id/saved_circuits_title"
    android:id="@+id/saved_circuits_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/saved_circuits_scroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In my `HomeActivity` I have the following relevant code that populates the `HorizontalScrollView` with bitmaps

```
onCreate{
...
this.savedCircuitsScroll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.saved_circuits_scroll);
...
}

updateSavedCircuits(){
...// code to make an ImageView from a retrieved bitmap
newImageImage.setOnClickListener(this.thumbnailListener);
this.savedCircuitsScroll.addView(newImageImage);
...
}
```

How do I use Espresso to scroll to an ImageView at a specified index in my HorizontalScrollView and click it?

---

### What I've tried

I do not have ID's in my layout xml so an approach such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410613/android-espresso-scrolling-to-a-non-list-view-item) does not work:

```
onView( withId( R.id.button)).perform( scrollTo(), click());
```

I know you can [click on an item by index in a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396583/how-to-click-on-an-item-inside-a-recyclerview-in-espresso) and tried finding an analogous approach for `HorizontalScrollViews`:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.saved_circuits_scroll))
            .perform(HorizontalScrollViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));
```

Except `HorizontalScrollViewActions` does not exist.

or following [this blog](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/04/15/espresso-testing-recyclerviews/) I tried the following to at least click an item in the `HorizontalScrollView` at a specified index:

```
// Click item at position 3
onView(withHorizontalScrollView(R.id.scroll_view).atPosition(3)).perform(click());
// Convenience helper
public static HorizontalScrollViewMatcher withHorizontalScrollView(final int horizontalScrollViewId) {
    return new HorizontalScrollViewMatcher(horizontalScrollId);
}
```

except `HorizontalScrollViewMatcher` does not exist.

What do we do for `HorizontalScrollView`? It isn't a descendant of `ScrollView` so the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25417769/2734863) suggests I need to implement my own custom `ViewAction`. All I want to do is scroll to an item in a `HorizontalScrollView` by index and click it. Is this really needed? If this is what I need to do, how do I go about implementing this custom `ViewAction`?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so in my particular case I found out that my scroll views had no ID associated with them (or none that I could reach reasonably, hence I couldn't use Mody's answer). However, they did have a tag associated with them so I could use Espresso's [withTagValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html#withTagValue(org.hamcrest.Matcher%3Cjava.lang.Object%3E)) ViewMatcher instead. Each view was associated with a circuitProject object (of course for you it may be different). And I have access to the following:

```
ArrayList<CircuitProject> circuitProjects = new ArrayList<>();
```

The index of a `circuitProject` object happens to be the position of the associated view in the `HorizontalScrollView`. The tag is the folder the `circuitProject` object is saved to. From here it is straightforward to get the behaviour I need with Espresso scrolling to a particular index in the `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
onView(withTagValue(withStringMatching(circuitProject.getFolderID()))).perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I got it by using:

```java
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.itemTextView), withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE), withText(R.string.categories))).perform(scrollTo(), click())
```

`R.id.itemTextView` is a TextView (with text `R.string.categories`) added dynamically to the `LinearLayout`:

```xml
<HorizontalScrollView>
  <LinearLayout>
      ... [child added dynamically]
  </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this matcher.

```
public static Matcher<View> withIdAndParentId(final int viewId, final int parentId) {
    Assert.assertTrue(viewId != -1);
    Assert.assertTrue(parentId != -1);

    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
            return view.getId() == viewId && isThereParentWithIdInHierarchy(view);
        }

        private boolean isThereParentWithIdInHierarchy(View view) {
            ViewParent viewParent = view.getParent();
            if (viewParent == null || !(viewParent instanceof ViewGroup))
                return false;

            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) viewParent;

            return parent.getId() == parentId || isThereParentWithIdInHierarchy(parent);
        }
    };
}
```

This is the way to use it :

```
onView(withIdAndParentId(R.id.YOUR_PARTICULAR_VIEW_ID, R.id.horizontalScrollViewId)).perform(scrollTo(), click());
```

Hope, it helps.